# Converting HSV to RGB in opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

My python code:

```
import numpy as np
hsvimg = np.zeros(10,10,3)
hsvimg[:,:,0] = np.linspace(0.2722,0.4722,10)
hsvimg[:,:,1] = np.linspace(0.5722,0.6522,10)
hsvimg[:,:,2] = np.ones(10)
```

how can i convert  hsv image to rgb, only using opencv

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find the answer on many tutorials (e.g. [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)) and on OpenCV documentation for [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).

```
rgbimg = cv2.cvtColor(hsvimg, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
```

Note that OpenCV stores RGB values inverting R and B channels, i.e. BGR. So you probably need this instead:

```
bgrimg = cv2.cvtColor(hsvimg, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalid number of channels in input image:
'VScn::contains(scn)'
where
'scn' is 4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).