# Generate random Pastel colour

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to generate a random pastel colour.

Is it correct to say that a pastel colour has a low value/intensity value (HS**V**)? Therefore something like this should generate random pastel colours: `Vec3b randPastel = Vec3b(rng.uniform(0, 180), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 50))`

My current function fails. It only ever creates black BGR colours for some reason:

```
Vec3b randPastelBGR()
{
    Mat hsv(1, 1, CV_8UC3);
    cvtColor(hsv, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
    hsv.at<Vec3b>(0, 0) = Vec3b(rng.uniform(0, 180), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 50));
    cvtColor(hsv, hsv, CV_HSV2BGR);
    return hsv.at<Vec3b>(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time, and only if it hasn't been asked before. I removed the [duplicate part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373527/converting-hsv-to-rgb-in-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

Pastels are mostly white, i.e. they have low Saturation. Not zero, though, because that would be entirely white (or grey). As you noticed, with a low Value you get dark colors. You want a fairly high Value, and might not even want a random one. (Exactly which color parts have to be random, and why?)

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar. I just very quickly tried `105*Rand() + 150` for each value of RGB, and it seemed to work pretty well. That will give you values between 150 and 255, i.e. lighter colors. This wasn't in c++, but the software I'm using makes values of 0 to 1 for `Rand()`.